# How to display solid line in a group when there is no value?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, group-by

I need to display a solid line under year 2015 in my row group. 
In a properties I entered my expression `=IIF(Fields!YearNum.Value=2015,"Solid",Nothing)`
But because some months don't have values the line is disrupted.
[image]

What would be the way to solve this problem?

Here is the t-sql for that tablix

```
SELECT      CAST(B.YearNum as varchar(10))+ ' Submitted'  as Type,
                1 as OrderNum,
                ISNULL(COUNT( ControlNo),0) Count,
                b.YearNum, b.MonthNum, b.MonthName
    FROM        tblCalendar b 
                    LEFT JOIN   ClearanceReportMetrics a  ON b.MonthNum = MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Argonaut Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry' 
    WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate) IN (2016, 2015) 
    GROUP BY    b.YearNum, b.MonthNum,b.MonthName

UNION ALL

    SELECT      CAST(b.YearNum as varchar(10)) +' Quoted'  as Type,
                2 as OrderNum,
                ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN QuotedPremium IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Count,          
                b.YearNum, b.MonthNum,b.MonthName
    FROM        tblCalendar b 
                    LEFT JOIN   ClearanceReportMetrics a  ON b.MonthNum = MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Argonaut Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
    WHERE           YEAR(EffectiveDate) IN (2016, 2015)  --AND CompanyLine = 'Plaza Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
    GROUP BY    b.YearNum, b.MonthNum,b.MonthName

UNION ALL

        SELECT  CAST(b.YearNum as varchar(10)) +' Bound' as Type,
                3 as OrderNum,
                ISNULL(sum(case when TransactionType = 'Policy' then 1 ELSE 0 END),0) as Binds,
                b.YearNum,
                b.MonthNum,             
                b.MonthName             
                FROM    tblCalendar b
        LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics a ON b.MonthNum = MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) and b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) --Coming from Production Report, NOT from Clearance!!!!!!!!!!!
                AND CompanyLine = 'Argonaut Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
        WHERE   b.YearNum IN (2016, 2015)
        GROUP BY b.YearNum,b.MonthNum,b.MonthName   

UNION ALL

    SELECT      CAST(b.YearNum as varchar(10)) +' Declined' as Type,
                4 as OrderNum,
                ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN  Status = 'Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),0) as  Count,
                b.YearNum, b.MonthNum,b.MonthName
    FROM        tblCalendar b 
                    LEFT JOIN   ClearanceReportMetrics a  ON b.MonthNum = MONTH(a.EffectiveDate) AND b.YearNum=YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
                    AND CompanyLine = 'Argonaut Insurance Company' AND Underwriter <> 'Batcheller, Jerry'
    WHERE       YEAR(EffectiveDate) IN (2016, 2015)
    GROUP BY    b.YearNum, b.MonthNum,b.MonthName
```

Also tried to change NULL values to 0. But still gives me the same result
[image]

Comment: I have never found a simple way to do this that works well. You can use an IIf to convert a 0 to a space and anything else to a number-as-text, but then you lose your ability to add things up sometimes when it's an Excel. If this is a standard pattern, you can just make a determination based on it being an even row. You can also add a rectangle over the top of the box with a solid line on the bottom that is only visible when the year is 2015.

Comment: Is any chance I can just do color pattern ? Like 2 rows 2016 submitted and 2015 submitted would be one color and so on?

Comment: why not change those nulls to 0?

Comment: I tried. It gives me the same. I dont know why :)

Comment: I attached a picture with 0 values

Comment: Why does july 2015 Quoted have a solid line? It is `0` also.

Comment: Thats a good question. I dont understand how this tool works. I even tried to modify my query and get -1 instead of 0. And it still doesnt give me solid line

Answer (score 0):

You can handle missing values like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!YearNum.Value=2015 Or IsNothing(Fields!YearNum.Value) = 1,"Solid",Nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me the same

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is:
In the properties, BotderStyle
For Top  I wrote expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2016 Quoted","Solid",
IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2016 Bound","Solid",
IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2016 Declined","Solid",
Nothing)))
```

And for the Bottom expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2015 Submitted","Solid",
IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2015 Quoted","Solid",
IIF(Fields!Type.Value="2015 Bound","Solid",
Nothing)))
```

So basically those lines cancelling each other off, and filling up the gaps.